# preset printer settings while generating pdf in iText

Tags: java, pdf, printing, itext, itextpdf

Is it possible to preset print paper size as Legal using addViewerPreference method?
Document's paper size is custom (8.5" x 12"). I do not want to change it as it is being derived from some template.

However I would like to preset print paper size as legal.

Is there any way this could be achieved using addViewerPreference  method?

Maybe something like:

```
writer.addViewerPreference(PdfName.SIZE, *LEGAL*)
```

Comment: Please check ISO-32000-2 or the draft of my upcoming book "The ABC of PDF": https://leanpub.com/itext_pdfabc You'll discover that there's no such thing available in the PDF specification. `/PickTrayByPDFSize` is the closest to what you need.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie - I have a legacy app that still uses the older version of iText.jar. I can't find the class PdfName.PICKTRAYBYPDFSIZE parameter in it. The jar states iText.jar, so not sure about the version. Is it a newly added parameter? How do I address it using the old jar? lgpl.txt states Version 2, June 1991.